# How do I write a condition that runs only if a particular file has not already been converted in a bash script?

Tags: bash, scripts

Learning bash scripts. I have script that makes an output file with the same name (different ending). How do I write a condition that only runs if that particular file has not already been converted to the other file ending?

For example a new file comes in and I only want to convert it instead of all of them again.

```
for file in /video_recordings/*.flv; 

do ffmpeg -threads 2 -i "$file" "${file%.flv}".mp4; 

done;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `-e` shell test to determine if the target file exists. From `help test`:

```
  -e FILE        True if file exists.
```

So for example

```
for file in /video_recordings/*.flv; do 
  if [ ! -e "${file%.flv}".mp4 ]; then
    ffmpeg -threads 2 -i "$file" "${file%.flv}".mp4 
  fi
done
```

or more compactly

```
for file in /video_recordings/*.flv; do 

  [ -e "${file%.flv}".mp4 ] || ffmpeg -threads 2 -i "$file" "${file%.flv}".mp4 

done
```

---

If you prefer, you can invert the logic and use a C-style `continue` to skip files that have already been converted:

```
for file in /video_recordings/*.flv; do 

  if [ -e "${file%.flv}".mp4 ]; then
    continue
  fi

  ffmpeg -threads 2 -i "$file" "${file%.flv}".mp4 

done
```

or

```
for file in /video_recordings/*.flv; do 

  [ -e "${file%.flv}".mp4 ] && continue

  ffmpeg -threads 2 -i "$file" "${file%.flv}".mp4 

done
```